# Passing in Variables in Python to SQL Query

Tags: python, sql

When I run the SQL query below I get the error **print(db.execute("SELECT * FROM (?);"), (tableName))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error**

```
db = sqlite3.Connection(":memory:")
db.execute("CREATE TABLE Students(name);")
tableName = "Students"
var1 = "Jon"
var2 = "Steve"
var3 = "Chuckie"
db.execute("INSERT INTO Students VALUES (?), (?), (?)", (var1, var2, var3))
print(db.execute("SELECT * FROM (?);"), (tableName))
```

What is the correct way to pass in parameters to a SQL query?

Comment: You cannot parametrize table name. If you try to concatenate/interpolate query string it would be possible but without proper quoting it would lead to SQL Injection.

Comment: I need to parametrize the table name, what would be the best way to do this then? @LukaszSzozda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't dynamically bind object names in SQL, only values. For such a behavior, you'll have to resort to string manipulation:

```
queryTemplate = 'SELECT * FROM %s'
tableName = 'Students'
query = queryTemplate % tableName

print(query)
```

**EDIT:**
To address the concerns in the comment - yes, this technique is indeed more vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. The common practice to protect against SQL Injection in such scenarios is to use a whitelist of allowed tables.

E.g.:

```
allowedTables = ['students', 'teachers']
if tableName not in allowedTables:
    raise ValueError('Wrong table')
```

Comment: `Students; DROP TABLE ...; --`

Comment: How do you protect against such a SQL injection?

Comment: @laddie_03 probably by using a whitelist of some sorts. See my edited answer for a simple implementation

Comment: Does the python string function .format() work for SQL queries?

Comment: Are we still using the modulo operator for string interpolation? The [consensus years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/string-formatting-vs-format) is to use `str.format`. In fact, even Python's [PEP 3101](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) advises so! That's like using the [implicit over explicit join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins) in SQL which ANSI-1992 recommended the current standard.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the values in a tuples,

```
query = ("INSERT INTO  billed_items(item_name,billed_qty,price,item_bill_series) VALUES(?,?,?,?)")
c.execute(query,((name),(no),(price),(series))
conn.commit()
```